# How to optimize IN constraint query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization, in-clause

Following is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.record_id IN (
    SELECT  t2.record_id FROM  t2 
        INNER JOIN t3 ON CONCAT(t2.case_number,t2.courtfile_type) = CONCAT(t3.case_number,t3.courtfile_type))
```

It contain `IN` constraint which is taking lot of time to extract result from `database.Database` is huge obviously.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Is all the fields which are used for IN query and for JOIN is having Index. If not, do add index and try EXPLAIN the same query again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**USING JOIN**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.record_id = t2.record_id 
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.case_number = t3.case_number AND t2.courtfile_type = t3.courtfile_type
```

**USING EXISTS**

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t2.record_id 
                  FROM  t2 INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.case_number = t3.case_number AND t2.courtfile_type = t3.courtfile_type
                  WHERE t1.record_id = t2.record_id )
```

Check the execution plan of the query using `EXPLAIN` keyword and do proper indexing on tables.

Comment: Just bear in mind that using `JOIN` could result in duplicates, if this is the case the select would have to be `SELECT DISTINCT t1.*` (although I don't advocate using SELECT *, since I don't what columns are in T1 I have no choice but to write it)

Comment: @GarethD I also agree with you about `SELECT *`. But I was not aware of table structure so I had written the `*`